# How to create an object from the class in subdirectory in Java

Tags: java

I started studying Java.
One part I got stuck is about how to create and use object which is originated from other class.

Directory structure:

```
/temp_dir/Java_code  
  Main.java  
  /java_db_code/  
    User_Table.java
```

Source codes are like these.

```
// File: /temp_dir/Java_code/Main.java

package temp_dir.java_code; // Package configuration of this java file
import temp_dir.java_code.java_db_code.User_Table; // import other class

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      int temp=5;

      // Create obj_user_table object from User_Table class located in package of temp_dir.java_code.java_db_code.User_Table, through its int parameterized constructor
      User_Table obj_user_table=new User_Table(temp);

      System.out.println(obj_user_table);
      // Expected: obj_user_table object

      System.out.println(obj_user_table.user_a);
      // Expected: 5
  }
}
```

```
// File: /temp_dir/Java_code/java_db_code/User_Table.java

package temp_dir.java_code.java_db_code;

public class User_Table
{
  public User_table(int a)
  {
    this.user_a=a;
  }
}
```

Run

```
cd /temp_dir/Java_code
javac -d . Main.java ./java_db_code/User_Table.java
```

Error

```
./java_db_code/User_Table.java:22: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public User_table(int a)
         ^
1 error
```

I wrote `public User_table(int a)` in `User_Table.java` as the constructor
But I don't know why error says that `invalid method declaration; return type required`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method names are case sensitive: `User_table` is not the same as `User_Table` (notice the capital T). The constructor must have the same exact name as the class, so use `User_Table`.

Still, the compiler will complain about one other thing once you fix that: in the constructor you do

```java
this.user_a=a;
```

But `user_a` is not declared in your class, which will make the compiler throw an error. To fix that, you just have to declare it in the class; since you want to access the field outside the class (for example, in `Main.main()`) make it `public`:

```java
public class User_Table
{
  public int user_a;

  public User_table(int a)
  {
    this.user_a=a;
  }
}
```

As a recommendation, you should really consider following the Java naming and style conventions:
 - You should use more whitespaces: `this.user_a = a`, `int temp = 5`, `obj_user_table = new`
 - Class names use the `UpperCamelCase`, with no underscores: `UserTable`
 - Method and variable names use the `lowerCamelCase`, with no underscores: `userA`

This won't change the functionality of the code, but it will make it more readable and standard for other Java users.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you for all answers, and sorry for the mistake and too basic question

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for a class `User_Table` needs to be named `User_Table`, not `User_table` (mind the `t`/`T`)!

With the wrong spelling, your method is just that, a method, not a constructor, so it has to have a return type (or `void` if you don't want to return anything).

Comment: (the class also doesn't have a `user_a` field)

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo here:

```
public User_table(int a)
```

rename it to:

```
public User_Table(int a)
```

As `Java` is `Case-Sensitive`, so you need to write exact names for java to detect is as `Constructor`